# Rotate single application in Windows

Tags: gratis, windows-7, display

I am looking for a program which can rotate a single program like a music player or a web browser in all angles (90, 180, 270, 0). I don't want to rotate the entire screen which can be done be **Ctrl + Alt + Arrow Keys**.

The software should be free and able to run on Windows 7. Any display driver configuration to achieve that is also ok.